# Is it possible to change a suggested edit decision?

Tags: support

I just noted that I misunderstood the change I have just reviewed.

**edit**

Luckily it turns out that I was stupid again and that my decision happened to be OK. But the question is pending nonetheless, of course.

The edited post is not by me. This is the link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/74669

I wasn't aware of these approve vs. reject statistics before. Funny to compare:

**Reviewer Stats**

- Community has approved 2559 edit suggestions and rejected 447 edit suggestions
- Hauke Laging has approved 114 edit suggestions and rejected 10 edit suggestions
- John WH Smith has approved 69 edit suggestions and rejected 45 edit suggestions

From 8% to 39%.

Comment: Was this to one of your posts or someone else's? Could you give us a link to the suggested review?

Comment: @terdon added the link

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88096/change-edit-approval-rejection (3+ years old post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way of changing the decision, no. In this particular case, I wouldn't worry about is since the OP has already dealt with the edit accordingly.

If something similar happens again, just go in and edit the post directly yourself. Since you have enough rep to be able to edit without needing approval, that is the simplest solution.